# Register Wordpress sidebars based delimited user-supplied input

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, filtering, sidebar

I have an input theme mod which returns the following values:

`sideone:1,sidetwo:1,sidethree:0`

This is a multiple checkbox input and each element before "," represents a sidebar - a checkbox...the number before ":" represents its state, `1` for active and `0` for inactive.

Can I loop over these values and register sidebars for the elements that are active?

```
[
    ['sideone', '1'],
    ['sidetwo', '1'],
    ['sidethree', '0'],
]
```

It is possible to register sidebars foreach array key that has a value of `1`? Not `0`.

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), because the question doesn't have enough information to diagnose the problem. Please edit your post accordingly so that we can help you. Please see [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922) for more details.

Comment: I added more info about my problem!

Answer (score 0):

This is how i fixed my problem:

As you know the input returns: sideone:1,sidetwo:1,sidethree:0 etc, 1 being for active state and 0 for inactive state. It can return 0 or 1 for each of this sidebars based on WP Customizer Control input.

```
$input = 'sideone:1,sidetwo:1,sidethree:0';
```

First i've made an array from that

```
$all_sidebars = explode(',',$input);
```

After that i removed from that array, any sidebar that has inactive state, in my case with 0, so if the input returns sideone:0 (etc) for one of the sidebars, that sidebar wont be registered anymore.

```
$active_only = array_diff($all_sidebars, ["sideone:0", "sidetwo:0", "sidethree:0"]);
```

After that i registered them with foreach

```
foreach ( $active_only as $id => $sidebar) {
    register_sidebar(
    array (
            'name'          => __( 'Footer Column ' . $id, 'wecodeart' ),
            'id'            => 'footer-'.$id,
            'before_widget' => '<div>',
            'after_widget'  => '</div>',
            'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ));
    }
```

So in this case only sidebar 1 and sidebar 2 will be registered.
Any better way to achive this ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would not bother doing a separate cycle to filter out the disqualified sidebars.  Just perform a check while you iterate and register the sidebars.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PM9mN))

```
$input = 'sideone:1,sidetwo:1,sidethree:0';

foreach (explode(',', $input) as $pair) {
    if (preg_match('/^([^:]+):1$/', $pair, $m)) {
        register_sidebar([
            'name'          => __('Footer Column ' . $m[1], 'wecodeart'),
            'id'            => 'footer-' . $m[1],
            'before_widget' => '<div>',
            'after_widget'  => '</div>',
            'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h2>',
        ]);
    }
}
```